# Infinite scrolling gradient background

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi, repeating-linear-gradient

I've searched and not found this question answered on SO, so I'm asking it here directly.

Does anyone have a clean method to create an infinitely scrolling gradient background? (the gradient shifts, so you can follow the colors from one side/corner to the other)

I've done this in VB like 15 years ago, but it's been so long since I touched VB it's all greek to me.

Assuming someone has done something like this in C# before-- Think demo scene kind of animation.

The VB code snippet is from a working form background I did many years ago, it doesn't scroll so much as bounce back and forth from edge to edge.

```
Private Sub picCanvas_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(-10, -10, Me.ClientSize.Width + 20, Me.ClientSize.Height + 20)
    Dim halfw As Integer = CType(Me.ClientSize.Width, Integer)
    Dim br As New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(-120, 500), New Point(Me.ClientSize.Width + 120, 0), Color.Red, Color.Blue)
    Dim color_blend As New ColorBlend
    color_blend.Colors = New Color() {Color.Black, Color.Purple, Color.Teal, Color.Purple, Color.Black}
    m_Theta += m_Delta
    color_blend.Positions = New Single() {0, 0.01, m_Theta, 0.99, 1}
    br.InterpolationColors = color_blend
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rect)
    br.Dispose()
    If (m_Theta > 0.75) Or (m_Theta < 0.25) Then m_Delta = -m_Delta
End Sub
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in getting this kind of thing to work in WinForms using only GDI and brushes, no XML or anything please ^^/

Comment: Can you explain what kind of *effect* you want to achieve? This looks like a semi-diagonal gradient that just fills the client area, so it's not clear what *infinite scrolling* means; if you actually want the blend to adapt to a scrolling surface, you have to use DisplayRectangle instead of ClientRectangle and invalidate in `OnScroll()` -- Are `m_Theta` and `m_Delta` meant to make the mid teal section *fluctuate*? What's `halfw` for? -- Is the question something like: *can you translate this to C#*? -- BTW, you don't set the location of Controls in the `Paint` handler

Comment: Wouldn't any infinitely scrolling gradient with a vertical component would just be a solid color?

Comment: @Jimi my snippet was more an example- I was trying to get a continuous 1-direction scroll of all colours but the best I could get to work seamlessly was just bouncing back and forth. The m_Theta was just the position that went up and down. -- wanting more of a picture-box or panel with a gradient that's always flowing from left-to-right, endlessly. It *will* be a window background in OnPaint for an 'About' window at some point, but for now just proof-of-concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure this is what you're trying to do, anyway, from the semi-pseudo code presented here, it appears you want to shift the position of a gradient fill along an axis.

It appears the fill is meant to be inclined, so I've added means to determine a rotation angle.
I've kept the LinearGradientBrush to generate the blended fill, though the combination of GraphicsPath and [PathGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.pathgradientbrush) is probably more flexible.

To *move* the gradient fill, I've used a standard `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  It's used to translate the fill, incrementing a value that is then set to the translation components of a [Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix) in the OnPaint override of a double-buffered Form used as canvas (of course, you can use a PictureBox instead)

The Matrix is also used to rotate the fill, in case it's needed

The Timer's `Tick` handler also verifies other conditions (bool Fields), that can be used to alter the fill:

- `useThetaShift` enables semi-dynamic motions of the blend intervals (the `Position` Property)
- `useTriangular` enables and alternate blending feature, generated by the [SetBlendTriangularShape()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush.setblendtriangularshape) method, which considers only the starting and ending Colors of the LinearGradientBrush and defines the center point of the Colors' fall-off

The sample Form shown here can also be set to auto-scroll, the blending is extended to the DisplayRectangle
The blend is animated also when a modal Dialog is shown (you mentioned an About Window...)

```
internal class SomeForm : Form {
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer gradientTimer = null;

    public SomeForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (components is null) components = new Container();
        ResizeRedraw = true;

        startColor = blendColors[0];
        meanColor = blendColors[1];
        endColor = blendColors[blendColors.Length - 1];
        gradientTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(components) { Interval = 100 };
        gradientTimer.Tick += GradientTimer_Tick;
        gradientTimer.Start();
    }

    float theta = .0f;
    float delta = .005f;
    float tringularShift = .25f;
    float tringularShiftDelta = .015f;
    float speed = 7.5f;
    float rotation = 0f;

    private Color[] blendColors = new[]{ 
        Color.Black, Color.Purple, Color.Teal, Color.Purple, Color.Black
    };
    Color startColor = Color.Empty;
    Color endColor = Color.Empty;
    Color meanColor = Color.Empty;
    PointF translateMx = PointF.Empty;
    bool useThetaShift = false;
    bool useTriangular = false;

    private void GradientTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (useTriangular) {
            tringularShift += tringularShiftDelta;
            tringularShift = Math.Max(Math.Min(tringularShift, 1.0f), .35f);
            if ((tringularShift >= 1.0f) | (tringularShift <= .35f)) tringularShiftDelta*= -1;
        }

        if (useThetaShift) {
            theta += delta;
            theta = Math.Max(Math.Min(theta, .15f), 0f);
            if ((theta >= .15f) | (theta <= 0f)) delta*= -1;
        }

        translateMx = PointF.Add(translateMx, new SizeF(speed, speed));
        if (Math.Abs(translateMx.X) >= short.MaxValue) translateMx = PointF.Empty;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var display = DisplayRectangle;
        using (var mx = new Matrix(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, translateMx.X, translateMx.Y))
        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(display, startColor, endColor, rotation)) {
            var colorBlend = new ColorBlend(blendColors.Length) {
                Colors = blendColors,
                Positions = new float[] { .0f, .25f + theta, .5f + theta, .75f + theta, 1.0f },
            };
            brush.InterpolationColors = colorBlend;
            mx.Rotate(rotation);
            brush.Transform = mx;
            if (useTriangular) brush.SetBlendTriangularShape(.5f, tringularShift);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, display);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        // Move to OnFormClosed() if this action can be canceled
        gradientTimer.Stop();
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}
```

I cannot post an animation here, because of the size. You can see how it work directly on Imgur:
[Animated LinearGradientPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfnS4.jpg)

Comment: You freaking NAILED IT, I love you man, thank you SO VERY MUCH <3

Comment: PS; Why did you remove the "C#" and "(winforms)" from the title? It would've made this solution much easier to find via search-engines wouldn't it?  This is sincerely the only solution I've found readily available on any site that my google-fu has produced.. All others refer to XML, Unity and/or XNA, or CSS for webpages. Clearly indicating this was/is GDI/winforms seems like a necessity for search results, to me, anyway. Either way, thank you so very much for the solution, it's beautiful my friend ^^/

Comment: I've removed those parts because the general advice it use tags to specify these details, avoiding *Title Pollution*. Of course you can change the title to whatever else, if you prefer a different *layout*, my edit is not written in stone -- You're welcome, BTW :)